# При инициализации в коде возникает ошибка

Tags: c#, winforms, классы

При инициализации в коде возникает ошибка  **"Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта"**

Ошибка в строке **

> if (s.pr[0] == title)

**

```
public class BUILDINGS
{
    public BUILDING[] buildings;
    public BUILDINGS(int n)
    {
        buildings = new BUILDING[n];

    }
    public BUILDING this[int i]
    {
        get { return buildings[i]; }
        set { buildings[i] = value; }
    }

    public BUILDING this[string title]
    {
        get
        {
            BUILDING building = null;
            foreach (var s in buildings)
            {
                if (s.pr[0] == title)
                {
                    building = s;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return building;
        }
    }
}

public class BUILDING
{
    public string[] pr;
    public BUILDING()
    {
        pr = new string[9];
    }

    public string this[int i]
    {
        get { return pr[i]; }
        set { pr[i] = value; }
    }

    public string this[string title]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (title)
            {
                case "Адрес": return "Адрес           " + pr[0];
                case "Тип дома": return "Тип дома          " + pr[1];
                case "Количество этажей": return "Количество этажей            " + pr[2];
                case "Количество комнат": return "Количество комнат            " + pr[3];
                case "Площадь, кв.м.": return "Площадь, кв.м.            " + pr[4];
                case "Стены": return "Стены                " + pr[5];
                case "Строения": return "Строения            " + pr[6];
                case "Отделка": return "Отделка             " + pr[7];
                case "Площадь участка, сотки": return "Площадь участка, сотки             " + pr[8];
                case "Цена": return "Цена             " + pr[9];
                default: return null;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            switch (title)
            {
                case "Адрес": pr[0] = value; break;
                case "Тип дома": pr[1] = value; break;
                case "Количество этажей": pr[2] = value; break;
                case "Количество комнат": pr[3] = value; break;
                case "Площадь, кв.м.": pr[4] = value; break;
                case "Стены": pr[5] = value; break;
                case "Строения": pr[6] = value; break;
                case "Отделка": pr[7] = value; break;
                case "Площадь участка, сотки": pr[8] = value; break;
                case "Цена": pr[9] = value; break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: в приведенном коде нет заполнения массива `buildings` , по умолчанию все значения `null`

Comment: Это не C++ и не C.